# Обратиться к объекту, область видимости

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script>
try { 
    
    const p = {
        int: function(setti){
           alert('dsf');
        }
    }
    
} catch (err) {  

    console.log(err);
}
</script>
<body>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => p.int({}));
    </script>
</body>
```

Необходимо обернуть js код, ловить ошибки и записывать из в файл. Собственно с этим нет трудностей.

Вопрос в том, если оборачивать таким образом, а затем из html обращаться к объекту. То в таком случаи попросту не видит объявленную константу. Возможно это поправить?

```
<script>
const p = {};
try { 
    
    p.int = setti =>{
       p.gg();
    }
    p.gg = setti =>{
        alert('11dsf');
    }
} catch (err) {  
    console.log(err);
}

</script>
<body>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => p.int({}));
    </script>
</body>
```

Есть такой вариант, но блин. Все писал через 'this', придется много править...

Comment: так а зачем в try оборачивать объект, а не необходимые критичные вези внутри функции? сама конструкция не имеет никакого смысла в таком коде

Comment: Не совсем понимаю.  Смотрю на статистику, половина пользователей не запускает плеер. Вероятно у некоторых происходит ошибка в коде из-за которой собственно не работает js.

Comment: Рассчитываю переделать код, так чтобы в случаи ошибки, записать ее в файл. Чтобы знать что происходит у тех пользователей которым не удается запустить плеер. Как быть?

Comment: Добавил второй пример,  вроде все работает. Но придется обращаться к объектам через константу и вообще верно ли так делать?

Comment: @ДмитрийВарзанов, во втором примере ты можешь точно так же использовать `function` вместо стрелочных функций

Comment: Стрелочные функции визуально лучше, не хотелось бы от них отказываться.

Comment: Можно пожалуйста пример как быть, как писать через function, так чтобы все объекты были в одной константе?

Comment: @ДмитрийВарзанов, добавил ответ. Фактически, в текущем виде, твой `try..catch` - вообще ни на что не влияет. Попробуй добавить в вопрос больше информации с примером, более приближенным к реальному, чтобы было ясно - что именно ты хочешь в `try..catch` обернуть и почему.

Comment: @ДмитрийВарзанов. _Стрелочные функции визуально лучше, не хотелось бы от них отказываться_ - в первом примере у тебя нет стрелочных функций, поэтому и отказываться не от чего :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

объявление `const` видно только внутри `try`.

Однако, в данном случае нет смысла оборачивать **присваивание** в блок `try..catch` - так как оно не может вызвать исключение.

Таким образом сейчас твоим примеры одинаково работают как с `try..catch` так и без.

Если исключение происходит **при вызове** метода - `try..catch` должен быть объявлен **внутри** функции

```
<script>
    
    const p = {
        int: function(setti){
            try {
                alert('dsf');
            } catch(e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
    }

</script>
<body>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => p.int({}));
    </script>
</body>
```